# Math.pow(), но через цикл

Tags: java

Нужно сделать программу в которой пользователь вводит инпут, а затем вывести на экран квадрат числа, которое ввели.
Код неправильный определенно.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i+=2)
            System.out.println(n*i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот так если квадрат

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n*n);
    }
}
```

а если нужен pow через цикл то будет примерно так

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        int pow = scan.nextInt();

        int product = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<pow; i++) {
          product *=n;
        } 

        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

частный случай когда степень 2

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int product = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
          product *=n;
        } 

        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```